# How to get index of multiple scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, tags

i have horizontal and vertical scrollview, for example one scrollview have four button and and second scrollview have six button and more so, when i click on any button then got index of last scrollview view, i already using tag.

my problem is for example i click on third scroll then i want both tag 
third scroll tag and specific button tag.

[image]

Comment: what  you want to do actuallly?

Comment: i want like index of scroll and tag of specific scroll button. all images are button.

Comment: when i click on Extreme Flat Belly then i want scroll tag three and button tag one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first tag of scrollview in storyboard .
2. set tag to button dynamically.(while create button or add button to scrollview)
3. track your index as below :

   ```
   - (IBAction)clickonbutton:(UIButton *)sender {

   UIScrollView* yourscrollview = (UIScrollView*)[sender superview]; // track your scrollview as per your view hierarchy

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)yourscrollview.tag);

    NSLog(@"clicked button tag%@",sender.tag);

   }
   ```

Comment: any way to when i scroll horizontal then one view is zoom effect    in scrollview ?